# Python Selenium Find Element by Name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, webautomation

I am using Python / Selenium and am trying to select an input box that does not have an ID:

#### HTML

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email"
           class="form-control"
           name="quantity"
           placeholder="Type a quantity">
</div>
```

#### Code

```python
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("quantity")
```

What is the best way to select this element, by name?

Comment: Possibly for newer versions when using `find_element_by_name`  (Pylint): "`E1101: Instance of 'WebDriver' has no 'find_element_by_name' member (no-member)`". For example, Selenium 4.12.0.

Comment: Related: *[Selenium - Python - AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773206/selenium-python-attributeerror-webdriver-object-has-no-attribute-find-el)*. E.g., *"Selenium just removed that method in version 4.3.0"*

Answer (score 15):

[`find_element_by_name()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_name) method would fit here:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("quantity")
```

Comment: The answer is almost in the title ;)

Comment: now this is deprecated, use ind_element(by=By.NAME, value=name) instead

Comment: Typos are unhelpful. It is at least `find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)`

Comment: Something like "`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`" is required for "`By.NAME`" to work.

Comment: [A question about the import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73056864/).

Comment: From [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72342517/how-to-get-element-by-tag-name-or-id-in-python-selenium/72342544#72342544): *"Do not add the "by=" and "value=" portion to the code."*

Answer (score 4):

In September 2022 with Selenium 4.4.0 the correct answer would be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
inputElement = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value='quantity')
```

Comment: Yes, the "`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`" line is crucial. Otherwise the result may be (Pylint) *"`E0602: Undefined variable 'By' (undefined-variable)`"*

Comment: Though it does not work for a variable number of elements (dynamic content), say 0, 1, or 2: An ***exception is thrown***, stopping the test run, if the element does not exist: "`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element`"

Comment: And it, presumably, only returns the first element if there is more than one.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method to collect attributes from elements many times:

```
for i in browser.find_elements_by_class_name("form-control"):
    print i.get_attribute("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

Preferable is to use explicit wait:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
input_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'quantity')))
```

More about waits [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: *Why* is it preferable to use explicit wait?

Comment: Setting Explicit Wait is important in cases where there are certain elements that naturally take more time to load. If one sets an implicit wait command, then the browser will wait for the same time frame before loading every web element. This causes an unnecessary delay in executing the test script.